# How to get selected product details by id in Reactjs and Laravel Application

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I need is to display selected product details, I am using React and Laravel: After selecting one product, in my ProductDetails page should be shown details of the selected product. but I get details in only son format when I do **{JSON.stringify(pet)}**. When I bind it with my element it does not give any data. Please help me.

**Description.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Form from "./Form";
import Related from "./Related";
import WhySafari from "./WhySafari";
import {read} from "./apiCore";


const Pet = (props) =>{
const [pet, setPet] = useState({});
const [error, setError] = useState(false)

const loadSinglePet = id =>{
    read(id).then(data =>{
        if(data.error){
            setError(data.error);
        }else{
            setPet(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
 };

useEffect(() => {
    const id = props.match.params.id;
    loadSinglePet(id);
}, [props]);

return(
    <div>
        <div className="bradcam_area breadcam_bg">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                    <div className="bradcam_text text-center">
                        <h3>German Shepherd</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link> <i className="ti-angle-right"></i> </li>
                            <li><Link to="/list">Puppies for sale</Link> <i className="ti-angle-right"></i> </li>
                            <li><Link to="#">Golden Doodle</Link><i className="ti-angle-right"></i></li>
                            <li><Link to="#">German Shepherd</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section className="sample-text-area">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                {/* {JSON.stringify(pet)} */}
                <div className="col-lg-6">
                    <div className="gallery-container">
                        <div className="swiper-container gallery-main">
                            <div className="swiper-wrapper">
                                <div className="swiper-slide">
                                    <Link to="img/puppy/1.png" data-fancybox="group1">
                                        <img src="img/puppy/1.png" alt="Slide 01" />
                                    </Link>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div className="left-thumb">
                            <div className="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
                                <div className="swiper-wrapper">
                                    <div className="swiper-slide">
                                        <img src="img/puppy/1.png" alt="Slide 01" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="swiper-slide">
                                        <img src="img/puppy/1.png" alt="Slide 01" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="swiper-slide">
                                        <img src="img/puppy/1.png" alt="Slide 01" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div className="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                            <div className="swiper-button-next"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-6">
                    <div className="product-details">
                        <h1>{pet && pet.pbrd_display_name}</h1>
                        <ul className="dtails-price">
                            <li className="real-price">$3449</li>
                            <li className="old-price">$4469</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="product-specification">
                            <h4><strong>Puppy Id : </strong> #656171</h4>
                            <h4><strong>Color : </strong> Apricot</h4>
                            <h4><strong>DOB : </strong> August 19,2020</h4>
                            <h4><strong>Location : </strong> Stamford </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="call-section">
                            <div className="call-left">
                                <img src="img/phone.svg" />
                                <h4>Need a nuppy guidience? <span>(888)012 3456</span></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className="call-right">
                                <Link to="#" className="boxed-btn3">Financing Available</Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="decription-parra">
                            <h4>Description :</h4>
                            <p>The Cavachone is a designer breed of Cavalier King Charles Spaniel and Bichon Frise. The
                                appearance can vary greatly between dogs in a litter. Some dogs may have more Bichon
                                Frise appearance compared to other dogs in the litter that may have more of a Cavalier
                                King Charles Spaniel appearance. The Cavachone is an intelligent dog which is easy and
                                willing to learn. It is recommended that you begin socialization and training early in
                                the puppy's life. The puppy will get bored with training. You must vary the length of
                                the training sessions as well as variety in how the training is given.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

        <Form/>

        <WhySafari />

        <Related />

    </div>
    );
    };

    export default Pet;
```

**coreAPi.js**

here I call my Laravel API

```
export const read = (id) =>{
return fetch(`${API}/puppies/${id}`, {
    method: "GET",
})
.then(response =>{
    return response.json();      
})
.catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
});
};
```

please help me while fixing this problem.

Thanks in advance

[image: my description component]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify your JSON response.